How to quote ambiguous line-break hyphen?
Say someone wrote this sentence:

I like my co-
workers.

But I'm not sure whether the author meant to write "co-workers" (hard hyphen) or "coworkers" (soft hyphen added only for a line break).
Then should I quote the above sentence as

"I like my co-workers." or
"I like my coworkers."?

(Similar but distinct question: When quoting, must I also copy hyphens used to divide words that continue on the next line?)

I say it would only matter if there was an ambiguous interpretation - "co-workers" and "coworkers" are exactly equivalent terms, so it really doesn't matter.  If, however, you were concerned that someone might read it as "cow-orkers" (credit to Scott Adams), then maybe you'd have a case where the hyphen is needed.  I can't off-hand think of any real-world examples of that kind of ambiguity though.

@DarrelHoffman: There are some cases where use of hyphenation changes over time, and is indicative of the familiarity of the word to the original author, e.g. radio-active  later becoming radioactive.

Only indicate linebreaks when you cite poetry or ancient texts written in lines. When citing contemporary prose, ambiguous end-of-line hyphens should be clarified.

If typographic conventions are important (e.g. in a critical edition of a text), inquire with the author, if possible.

If asking the author is impossible or excessive, check if the text contains the word not across a line break to find out how the author writes it, with or without hard hyphen.

If the text doesn't contain an unbroken occurence of the word, check other texts by the author.

If no other texts by the author are available or they do not contain that word, try to figure out which variant of English the author writes and use the form correct or more common in that variant (e.g. British English seems to prefer co-worker while American English seems to prefer coworker, but that is just my hunch, make sure you properly research this).

If neither approach leads to a solution, randomly choose one variant.



Good suggestions, but instead of randomly choosing one variant as the last resort, would it not make more sense to quote the hyphen? My reasoning is that the hyphen is what's actually written on the page, so you have a good defense for why you quoted it in case the author or someone else complains that the quote is inaccurate.

@DanRomik The visual appearance of a printed prose text, including many line-end hyphens, is a result of typesetting and not what the author has written. Your reasoning that the hyphen is "actually written on the page" (i.e., intended by the author as a hard hyphen) is an arbitrary interpretation. In case of an ambiguous line-end hyphen, the chance that it is a soft versus a hard hyphen is 50%. Your choice is therefore the result of a mental coin toss (i.e., random). As such, it actually follows my suggestion (no. 5) and is of course fine. But it is not reasonable.

I know I'm repeating myself here, but your misunderstanding makes me think it is necessary to emphasize this: In poetry, the visual representation of a text (including linebreaks) carries meaning. In prose it commonly does not. That is the reason why prose text is usually submitted to the publisher as a left-aligned manuscript (without soft hyphens) – to avoid ambiguities such as the present one. In prose, "what is written on the page" is not what the author has written. It is just one of many possible representations of the author's text and a result of design decisions by the typesetter.

I wouldn't quite say "random" necessarily though.  If for example the same maybe-hyphenated word appears more than once in the text, you should either hyphenate it always or never.  If you're inconsistent and hyphenate it sometimes and not others, it just looks sloppy.  (Unless it's hyphenated over a line break as in the original quoted text; inconsistency is allowable in that case.)

@DarrelHoffman I don't know what you mean. If the word appears elsewhere in the text, my no. 2 takes care of that. The comments above discuss the situation when there are no other instances of that word in the text.

As in other situations where you're quoting a text that contains potentially confusing or ambiguous elements, such as typos or misprints, or an unusual word, a common device that can be used to alert your readers to the issue and avoid the need to guess or interpret the quoted author's intent is the use of the adverb "sic".
In the current example, if you are unable to discern whether the author meant "co-workers" or "coworkers", you can quote the text as

I like my co-workers. [sic]

As @Ben's answer discusses, sometimes it is possible to fathom the author's original intent by contacting them or by studying the text for various clues that inform how to resolve the ambiguity. It's fine to do that in the current context, for example by following steps 1-4 in Ben's answer. But the "sic" device makes it unnecessary, or can at least be used as a last resort if other options fail.
The "sic" option also puts the emphasis on the fidelity of the quote. In a small and symbolic way it promotes truthfulness and accuracy, in a way that tossing a coin — the other answer's suggested last resort-solution — does not.

But sic is almost always used to indicate some error (or sometimes archaism) in the quoted text. So using sic here would be confusing to most readers.

@user182601 maybe so. With the coworkers/co-workers example I agree it comes across as either baffling or absurdly pedantic, because it’s hard to see why the person who put in the quote considers the distinction important. In other situations where the ambiguity introduced by the hyphen is more problematic, I think the use of “sic” would make more sense and is less likely to confuse people.
